Webpack file can't be found
I'm migrating a legacy js project to Symfony Encore, and the webpack builder is giving me this error:
"./frontend/src/application.js" contains a reference to the file "core-js/modules/web.timers.js".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

This only happens when a setInterval is present in the JS source. What is going on, I thought this was a default JS function?
Also, my webpack config contains this:
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = '3.38';
    })

So it seems like it's already doing something with corejs? Am I missing Babel plugins or something?
When disabling the Symfony Encore config for configureBabelPresetEnv I get no errors anymore? Weird, because in another Symfony project I never had problems and it's still enabled there.

Could this be related?: https://github.com/electron/forge/issues/3445
